# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

`import pandas as pd`

while running this code I have the following error.

```
C:\Users\user3\PycharmProjects\Customer_Revieww\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user3/PycharmProjects/Customer_Revieww/venv/cust_rev.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user3/PycharmProjects/Customer_Revieww/venv/cust_rev.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

please provide solution.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you installed `pandas` using `pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

You need to instal the module in the environment you are using in PyCharm.
This can be done from command line:

```
pip install pandas
```

As well as in PyCharm itself - see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fRhNd22io0).